# iOS Setters and Getters and Underscored Property Names

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have a NSString property named description, defined as follows:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *description;
```

I'm able to refer to it as _description when I define the getter, as follows:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return _description;
}
```

However, when I define a setter, as follows:

```
-(void)setDescription:(NSMutableString *)description
{
    self.description = description;
}
```

It breaks _description from the aforementioned getter (undeclared identifier). I know I can probably just use self.description instead, but why does this happen?

Comment: It is because you are overriding description method already available in NSObject class. Try using some other name for your property.

Comment: Also change your getter return type to similar to what your property declares.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@borrrden 's answer is very good. I just want to add some details.

Properties are actually just syntax sugar. So when you declare a property like you did:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *description;
```

It is automatically synthesized. What it means: if you don't provide your own getter + setter (see borrrden's answer),  an instance variable is created (by default it has name "underscore + propertyName"). And getter + setter are synthesized according to the property description that you provide (strong, nonatomic).
So when you get/set the property, it is actually equal to calling the getter or the seter. So

```
self.description;
```

is equal to `[self description]`.
And

```
self.description = myMutableString;
```

is equal to `[self setDescription: myMutableString];`

Therefore when you define a setter like you did:

```
-(void)setDescription:(NSMutableString *)description
{
    self.description = description;
}
```

It causes an infinite loop, since `self.description = description;` calls `[self setDescription:description];`.

Comment: Is it unnecessary to write `@synthesize description = _description;` then?

Comment: You can simply declare a property. Then an instance variable, getter and setter will be automatically created for you. But if you declare your own getter and setter, then instance variable is not created. So you should either `@synthesize` it or declare it manually in the `@interface { NSMutableString *_description}`. But it is a rare option nowadays :) If you need both custom getter and setter, you can use `@synthesize`. Otherwise you may skip it. And actually, if you don't implement some custom behaviour, you can skip getter and setter too. `@property` declaration is enough.

Comment: Thanks! So basically, if I don't have any custom behaviour for setting/getting, I can just declare it. Otherwise, define the methods and synthesize.

Comment: Oh, in the .m file, should I declare the properties in the interface or implementation? Will this affect the automatic getter/setter behaviour?

Comment: You always declare properties in the `@interface`. So usually you do it in the .h file. This way this property will be available to external classes. If you don't want other classes to be able to see this property, you can declare it in the private category in the .m file.
`@implementation` block can only contain `@synthesize` statements if they are necessary.

Comment: So if I don't want other classes to see the property, then I put them in the .m file. But does that mean the getters/setters will be similarly private?

Comment: Yes, it does. As I said, properties are just a syntax sugar. So when you declare a property, it is equal to declaring a getter and a setter at that position. By the way if I remember correctly (I don't have a mac nearby right now) even if you didn't declare a property, but you declared a method like `-(SomeDataType*)myMethod;`, you would still be able to use dot syntax like `myObject.myMethod`.

Answer (score 10):

1) `NSObject` already has a method named description.  Pick another name

2) Your setter is an infinite loop

But as to your actual question:  The compiler will only autogenerate backing variables if you do not override both methods.

P.S. No, you can't just "use self.description instead" because then your getter would also be an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks! I'll change the name and change the setter. I think that using `@synthesize description = _description;` might solve my problem (or, after I have to change the names anyway).

Comment: Yes, that is one way to force the compiler to synthesize the variable even if you override both.

Comment: A quick note that the "backing variables" referenced above are called ivars.

Comment: @synthesize description = _description cannot fix any problem, because that's what is happening anyway if you don't synthesize at all.

Comment: @gnasher729 If you override both the getter and setter, the ivar will not be automatically synthesized.