# objective C underline variable and self variable different

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables

I am working on the demo app of stanford university ios7, here is the problem:

```
#import "YSHViewController.h"
@interface YSHViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipsLable;
@property (nonatomic) int flipCount;

@end

@implementation YSHViewController

- (void)setFlipCount:(int)flipCount
{
    _flipCount = flipCount;
    _flipsLable.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d",_flipCount]; // not working
    NSLog(@"%@", _flipsLable.text);
    NSLog(@"%@", self.flipsLable.text);
    self.flipsLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d",_flipCount];
}

- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    //if (sender.currentTitle.length != 0) {
    if ([sender.currentTitle length]) {
        //UIImage *cardImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback"];

        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        //UIImage *cardImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardfront"];

        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardfront"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTitle:@"A♣︎" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    _flipCount++;
    NSLog(@"%i",_flipCount); //
//    self.flipCount++;

}
```

the flipLable number won't add but nothing wrong with the app.But I change the code with self,it works:

```
#import "YSHViewController.h"

@interface YSHViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipsLable;
@property (nonatomic) int flipCount;

@end

@implementation YSHViewController

- (void)setFlipCount:(int)flipCount
{
//    _flipCount = flipCount;
//    _flipsLable.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d",_flipCount]; // not working
//    NSLog(@"%@", _flipsLable.text);
//    NSLog(@"%@", self.flipsLable.text);
    _flipCount = flipCount;
    self.flipsLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d",self.flipCount];
}

- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    //if (sender.currentTitle.length != 0) {
    if ([sender.currentTitle length]) {
        //UIImage *cardImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback"];

        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        //UIImage *cardImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardfront"];

        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardfront"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTitle:@"A♣︎" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
//    _flipCount++;
//    NSLog(@"%i",_flipCount); //
    self.flipCount++;

}
```

So, what's the difference of the two variables to set the number of fliCount.

Comment: its equal, but I recommend you use self.property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is the reason it doesn't work: `_flipCount++;`.

`self.flipCount` is a property. `_flipCount` is an instance variable, where that property value is stored by default. When you write `self.flipCount`, you, in essence, call a getter for this property: `[self flipCount]`. When you write `self.flipCount++;`, you call a getter, then a setter. Very roughly it can be written like so:

```
[self setFlipCount:[self flipCount] + 1];
```

And your custom setter gets called. However, when you write `_flipCount++`, you access the instance variable directly, so your custom setter is ignored. That's why your `flipLable` is not updated in the first case.

Have a look here: [iOS setters and getters and underscored property names (SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017073/ios-setters-and-getters-and-underscored-property-names/17017207#17017207)

Note that in general you should use getters and setters (i.e. `self.flipCount`) instead of instance variables to access the data you want, even if you have a direct access to instance variables, because getters/setters might implement some specific behavior. For instance, lazy initialization, or, like in your case, UI updates.

You only usually work with instance variables (i.e. `_flipCount`) in getters/setters and in `init` and `dealloc` methods (it is an Apple's recommendation to use instance variables there, because custom getters/setters might do something unpredictable, if the object have not yet been completely initialized, or have been partially destroyed, and it also can provoke KVO-related issues).

Comment: Thanks for telling me so much!