# unrecognized selector sent to instance @dynamic

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic

I was doing some research on the differences @dynamic and @synthesize, so I make a small (simple) example:

```
@interface Classe : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int value;

@end


@implementation Classe

@synthesize value;

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        Classe *cl = [[Classe alloc] init];
        cl.value = 50;
        NSLog(@"%d",cl.value);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

From what I understand with this my example, is that the 'synthesize' creates behind the scenes getters and setters methods, and as we have seen above I only do `cl.value = 50;`.

Now, let's talk about @dynamic, I hear that

> is merely a way to inform the system not to generate getters/setters
>   for the thing, that you (or someone else) will provide them for you.

Okay, if in my example above I change the `@synthesize` to `@dynamic` the application will give error returning the following message:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10010eeb0

This was because it was said that the compiler does not create the getters and setters methods, knowing this, how could I create the getters and setters methods manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you simply do. If your property has a name

```
@property (nonatomic) int value;
```

Then in your implementation you just define methods:

```
-(int)value {
    //your getter here
}

-(void)setValue:(int)newValue {
    //Your setter here
}
```

`@dynamic value;` tells compiler that it should NOT make default accessors.

But you don't need `@dynamic` to do it. You can just write a getter and a setter. You might need `@synthesize` though. Because if you specify your own getter **and** setter, the compiler won't generate an instance variable (`_value`) for you. To make it do it (if you need it), you will need `@synthesize`.

More about it: [SO: Getters, setters and underscore property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017073/ios-setters-and-getters-and-underscored-property-names/17017207#17017207).

Comment: Ok, thats IT, now if I save the value inside my property in this way: self.value, my app crash.. why? And how can I store the values?

Comment: @LettersBa, please, provide more info (update the question): what is the exact code you use? What kind of crash do you get?

Comment: Example, I use this code: -(void)setValue:(int)newValue {
    self.value = value;
}

Comment: If i USE this code to save the value in my property, the compiler now do a Infinite loop.

Comment: @LettersBa, this is exactly the topic discussed in the SO question I linked in the end. Please, read it.

Comment: I think the only time when you need `@dynamic` is when you don't synthesise the property and you don't provide your own getter and setter in the implementation but you do know there is going to be a getter and setter at run time e.g. if they are added by something else at runtime (NSManagedObject subclasses, for example).

Comment: Strange.. If I declare a variable with same name of my property like this: @interface Classe : NSObject{
    NSString *value;
}

Comment: So from what I understand, the dynamic is a kind of bridge, where we will not to set values for that particular property, but for other variables, correct?

Comment: So @dynamic is a kind of property who set values for other property (non-dynamic) and variables, right?

Comment: @LettersBa, no, @dynamic just tells the compiler not to worry, that `getter` and `setter` are not present at compile time. It's like a promise that they'll be there when the method is called, and the app won't throw `unrecognized selector` exception.